# mysql query to get count of individual ids

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Following mysql query will give a result as follows

```
$query = "SELECT PS.user_id, PS.pro_id
    FROM pro_Purchase AS PS
    INNER JOIN program_detail AS PD ON PD.program_master_id = PS.pro_id
    WHERE PD.program_type = 'program'
    AND PS.subscribe_status = '1'
    GROUP BY PS.`programs_subscribed_id`
    HAVING COUNT( `pro_id` ) > '1'
    ORDER BY PS.pro_id"
```

Result

```
user_id program_id
97      167     
12      172     
12      172     
216     173     
216     173     
215     173     
216     173     
12      173     
12      173     
12      173     
216     173
```

Here I want to get the `count` of each `program_id`

For eg:count(172),count(173) and so on.

```
id   count
172  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your query in a subquery and count in the outer query like this:

```
SELECT 
  user_id, COUNT(pro_id)
FROM
(
    SELECT PS.user_id, PS.pro_id
    FROM pro_Purchase AS PS
    INNER JOIN program_detail AS PD ON PD.program_master_id = PS.pro_id
    WHERE PD.program_type = 'program'
      AND PS.subscribe_status = '1'
    GROUP BY PS.programs_subscribed_id
    HAVING COUNT( pro_id ) > '1'
) AS Sub
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY pro_id;
```

**Note that:** in the query you posted you are grouping by `PS.programs_subscribed_id` and selecting `PS.user_id, PS.pro_id` in the `SELECT` clause which are neither in an aggregate function nor in the `GROUP BY` clause, so you won't get inconsistent data this way.

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT PS.pro_id, COUNT(PS.user_id)
FROM pro_Purchase AS PS
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT programs_subscribed_id
   FROM pro_Purchase 
   GROUP BY programs_subscribed_id
   HAVING COUNT( pro_id ) > 1
) AS PS2 ON PS.programs_subscribed_id = PS2.programs_subscribed_id
INNER JOIN program_detail AS PD ON PD.program_master_id = PS.pro_id
WHERE PD.program_type = 'program'
  AND PS.subscribe_status = '1'
GROUP BY PS.pro_id;
```

This way, the extra `JOIN` with the subquery:

```
   SELECT programs_subscribed_id
   FROM pro_Purchase 
   GROUP BY programs_subscribed_id
   HAVING COUNT( pro_id ) > 1
```

Will ensure that each row selected from the `pro_Purchase` table has `COUNT( pro_id ) > 1` for each  `programs_subscribed_id` and that's why you were grouping by `programs_subscribed_id` in your first query.